# group spatial data with spdplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, geospatial, r-sf

Hi and thanks for reading me
I am trying to group a dataset containing polygons of a city, to avoid having duplicate values, but when I try to use group_by (masked with the spdplyr package) the data is not grouped. Anyone know how I could do this? Thanks for the help

The code im using is the following:

```
# DATA:

 nombre_alcaldia                                                                     n
   <chr>                                                                       <POLYGON>
 1 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…
 2 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…
 3 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…
 4 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…
 5 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…
 6 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…
 7 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…
 8 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…
 9 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…
10 Álvaro Obregón  ((-99.18871 19.39475, -99.18868 19.39468, -99.18857 19.39442, -99.18…

# grouping

datos_esp1 |> 
  group_by(nombre_alcaldia) |> 
  summarise(n = geometry )
```

Comment: Provide `dput(x)` to provide sample dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link

https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/915

spdplyr cannot group_by geometries. There are two options,

1. You get unique geometries, instead of grouping by, based on actual extent.
2. You group_by X column to which later you join to a set of unique geometries.